# Is there a way to customize the labels of size on a bubble plot to whatever I'd like in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, size

As you can see on the image, R automatically assigns the values 0, 0.25... 1 for the size of the point. I was wondering if I could replace the 0, 0.25... 1 and make these text values instead while keeping the actual numerical values from the data.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
data(SLC4A1, package="ggplot2")

SLC4A1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE)


# bubble chart showing position of polymorphisms on gene, the frequency of each of these 
# polymorphisms, where they are prominent on earth, and p-value 

SLC4A1ggplot <- ggplot(SLC4A1, aes(Position, log10(Frequency)))+
  geom_jitter(aes(col=Geographical.Location, size =(p.value)))+
  labs(subtitle="Frequency of Various Polymorphisms", title="SLC4A1 Gene") +
  labs(color = "Geographical Location") +
  labs(size = "p-value") + labs(x = "Position of Polymorphism on SLC4A1 Gene") + 
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,4.5), trans = "reverse") +
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyver)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5,z = 1:5)

ggplot(df,aes(x = x, y = y, size = z)) +
           geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df,aes(x = x, y = y, size = z)) +
           geom_point() +
    scale_size_continuous(range = 1:2) # control range of circle size
```

[image]

See more here:
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_size.html